# Unix bash error - binary operator expected

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command

So below is the code i have in my bash script. I'm getting an error saying binary operator expected when i give the command 2 arguments (doesnt give error when i give 1 argument). It does change the file permissions when i give 2 arguments because i can see it when i do ls -l but it still gives me this error. How do i fix it?

```
for file in $@
do
    chmod 755 $file
done

if [ -z $@ ]
then
        echo "Error. No argument."
        exit $ERROR_CODE_1
fi
```

i have added this now

```
if [ ! -f "$*" ]
then
       echo "Error. File does not exist"
       exit $ERROR_NO_FILE
fi
```

But now when i enter more than 1 argument it just does everything in the if statement (i.e. prints error.file does not exist) even when the file does exist.

Comment: Don't change your question. If you have a *new* question you should post it as a new, instead of changing your *existing* question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing it another way: just ask how many parameters were passed:

```
...
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
...
```

You get the error in your code because the $@ variable expands to multiple words, which leaves the `test` command looking like this:

> [ -z parm1 parm2 parm3 ... ]

Answer (score 3):

`$@` is expanding to all the arguments, with spaces between them, so it looks like:

```
if [ -z file1 file2 file3 ]
```

but `-z` expects just one word after it. You need to use `$*` and quote it, so it expands into a single word:

```
if [ -z "$*" ]
```

This expands into:

```
if [ -z "file1 file2 file3" ]
```

Or just check the number of arguments:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
```

You should also put this check before the `for` loop. And you should quote the argument in the `for` loop, so you don't have problems with filenames that have spaces:

```
for file in "$@"
```

Comment: i have updated my code above in the question box and am getting a different error please can you help me. i am a beginner and need help.

Comment: `-f` expects just a single filename after it, but you're combining all the filename arguments into a single test.

Comment: If you have a different question, you should post a new question, not add it to a question that has already been answered.

Comment: Yes so how do i fix it. Please. For loop i guess.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. You should use `if [ ! -f "$file" ]` inside the `for` loop. Why would you test the entire argument list?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your parameters in double quotes to avoid word splitting and pathname expansion:

```
for file in "$@"
do
    chmod 755 "$file"
done

if [ -z "$*" ] # Use $* instead of $@ as "$@" expands to multiply words.
then
        echo "Error. No argument."
        exit "$ERROR_CODE_1"
fi
```

You can however change the code a little:

```
for file # No need for in "$@" as it's the default
do
    chmod 755 "$file"
done

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ] # $# Contains numbers of arguments passed
then
    >&2 printf 'Error. No argument.\n'
    exit "$ERROR_CODE_1" # What is this?
fi
```

Comment: i have updated my code above in the question box and am getting a different error please can you help me. i am a beginner and need help.